# join rows with same name by removing NA in r

Tags: r

Hello I need your support to join rows with the same name together and remove NA. In case of columns with the same name, a new column is created with a subscript, or combine it together with a comma.

I have this example dataframe:

```
name<-c("John","John","John","Luis","Luis")
may<-c("a",NA,NA,"a",NA)
june<-c(NA,"b",NA,NA,"a")
july<-c("d",NA,"c",NA,NA)
df<-data.frame(name,may,june,july)
```

having the following dataframe:

```
  name  may june july
1 John    a <NA>    d
2 John <NA>    b <NA>
3 John <NA> <NA>    c
4 Luis    a <NA> <NA>
5 Luis <NA>    a <NA>
```

I expect a result like the following:

```
  name may  june  july  july.2
1 John   a    b    c      d
2 Luis   a    a   <NA>   <NA>
```

or like the following:

```
  name  may june  july
1 John   a    b   c,d
2 Luis   a    a   <NA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `summarize` to concatenate strings together under the same "name".

In `summarize()`, if all records in the same column are `NA`, we fill that record with `NA`. If not, concatenate the strings without `NA`.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), ~ifelse(sum(is.na(.x)) == n(), NA, paste0(na.omit(sort(.x)), collapse = ","))))

# A tibble: 2 × 4
  name  may   june  july 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 John  a     b     c,d  
2 Luis  a     a     NA
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is just what I was looking for, only that when I add it with my data frame I have other variables before the name, is there a way to apply the code only in the last three columns?

Comment: @Johan You can do `summarize(across(may:july, ~ifelse(sum(is.na(.x)) == n(), NA, paste0(na.omit(sort(.x)), collapse = ","))))`